# What are the MediaWiki functions which alter categories in database?

Tags: mediawiki, categories, neo4j

I'm currently working on a project to change the category administration from Mediawiki to neo4j. (To store categories and relations with neo4j instead of the Mediawiki-MySQL DB)

I didn't found a special hook from Mediawiki for the category creation (When the category and categorylinks are stored to db). Now I try to replace the functions that insert, update and select the category table (MySQL).

Unfortunately I don't find a starting point from where to begin. Which file from Mediawiki should be altered? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The main update is done in [includes/LinksUpdate.php](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/includes/LinksUpdate.php?revision=85812&view=markup#l89). The relevant hooks are [LinksUpdate](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/LinksUpdate) and [LinksUpdateComplete](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/LinksUpdateComplete). There seem to be one or two other places where a sortkey is updated or a record is deleted. The reads from the table seem to be done all over the place as needed.